# Getting 'jQuery.Deferred exception' on AWS but not locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timepicker

When I load this locally everything works fine. But when deployed on AWS EC2, I am getting this error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).timepicker is not a function TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://ec2-URL:3000/page.html:42:31)
    at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js:2:29588)
    at k (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js:2:29902) undefined
```

My code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            interval: 60,
            minTime: '00',
            maxTime: '23:30',
            defaultTime: '07',
            startTime: '00:00',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true});
    });
    var shiftRows = 0;
</script>
</head>
```

I have tried sorting the order of the script loading differently but can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Script tag in the head should be avoided.

Comment: Weird, I've been reading the opposite on so many sites. Yet, when I tried putting this at the bottom of the body, it seems to work. Thanks!